# Using DataMapper with AnyPoint studio 5.2.1

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I downloaded AnyPoint studio 5.2.1 and have been trying to run some tests flows that include the use of the DataMapper transformer.

However, when that transformer is included in a flow, the following Maven dependency resolution issue occurs:

```
Failed to collect dependencies at com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules:mule-module-data-mapper:jar:3.7.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules:mule-module-data-mapper:jar:3.7.0: Could not transfer artifact com.mulesoft.muleesb.datamapper:parent:pom:3.7.0 from/to muleforge-repo (http://repository.muleforge.org): Connect to repository.muleforge.org:80 [repository.muleforge.org/199.119.127.133] failed: Connection refused
```

Is a license required to even run this locally within AnyPoint studio?

Answer (score 0):

There is no dependencies for using data mapper in Anypoint Studio - because it is deprecated in that version.  You can still download and include datamapper if you need:  https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/including-the-datamapper-plugin

However you would be better moving to the latest version and using Dataweave which is the go-forward Mule data transformation tool

As per your error message, I see a version mismatch between your Anypoint studio and data mapper. Could you please confirm if you have upgraded some components in your Anypoint Studio? If yes, you may want to uninstal that and try again. I have never experienced this issue.